# Intersystems Cache script character limit

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

what's the character limit (number of characters) which send command has and how can I change it?

If I run a long command , it's not getting send completely and an "S" is appended to the end of the string (and string is cut off)
so is there a way to change/see how many characters we can send?

script:

> send: Set tSql="SELECT count(*) AS cc FROM table WHERE id IN
>   ('1111111111','1111111112','1111111113','1111111114','1111111115','1111111116','1111111117','1111111118','1111111119','1111111120','1111111121','1111111122','1111111123','1111111124','1111111125','1111111126','1111111127','1111111128','1111111129','1111111130','1111111131','1111111132','1111111133')"

here's what I get in cache terminal:

> Set tSql="SELECT count(*) AS cc FROM table WHERE id IN
>   ('1111111111','1111111112','1111111113','1111111114','1111111115','1111111116','1111111117','1111111118','1111111119','1111111120','1111111121','1111111122','1111111123','1111111124','1111111125','1111111126','1111111127','1111111128','1111111129','1111111130','111S

As you see there's an S appended to the commmand which finally will result into syntax error

Answer (score 3):

The cleaner approach would be to create a class with methods, containing the implementations of whatever you want to achieve and then calling it via:

`send: Do ##class*Package.Class).Method(Arguments)`

and passing required parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how it limited, but I can say that, you can split any of your long data by multiple `send`. And it will looks like below

```
send: Set tSql="SELECT count(*) AS cc FROM table WHERE id IN 
send: ('1111111111','1111111112','1111111113','1111111114','1111111115',
send: '1111111116','1111111117','1111111118','1111111119','1111111120',
send: '1111111121','1111111122','1111111123','1111111124','1111111125',
send: '1111111126','1111111127','1111111128','1111111129','1111111130',
send: '1111111131','1111111132','1111111133')"
```